# What is the sign of the metric determinant?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, definition

I read that for the Levi-Civita symbol $\tilde{\epsilon}_{ijk}$, people somtimes define another version of the symbol with upper indices:
$$\tilde{\epsilon}^{ijk}=\text{sgn} (g) \tilde{\epsilon}_{ijk} $$
where $\text{sgn}(g)$ is the sign of the metric determinant. How is $\text{sgn}(g)$ computed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function. It's also handy to know the different conventions adopted by authors: see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292397)

Comment: Do you know how the metric determinant is defined?

Comment: @NiharKarve Thank you. Very useful.